# Best way to use shared memory that can be read directly by different processes without copy overhead

Tags: c#, .net, shared-memory, inter-process-communicat

I have an application where the initialization involves reading very large data from files (~ > 10 GB) and then performing some computations on this data (which is of type **Dictionary**). The initialization step takes a couple of hours every time even though my data is fixed/never changed. What I'd like to do is somehow use a process to pre-load these data into memory and another process on the same machine to read directly from it **all data only once, and without any COPY**. So far, I have found a couple methods:

- .Net Remoting with remote objects. However this approach bears the marshaling cost so wouldn't work for my case since the data transfer would result in twice as much memory at one point.
- Memory mapped files. This option still seems to require data copy and for my case it won't be ideal since I'd need to copy all >10GB of data. I have found some articles about using unsafe access to memory addresses but I don't exactly know how this works.
- WCF Named Pipes. This approach seems similar to remoting and still requires data transfer.

What's the most effective way for my scenario?

Answer (score 1):

If you're putting the data into a dictionary why not use any of the popular nosql key value stores (couchbase, riak, redis) then any process could work with the data. If you're totally opposed to that idea you could always use the NancyFx framework to host a local rest service endpoint in the "Host" application then any other applications that need to make use of the pre loaded data could interact with the services provided by the host.

Comment: I'm not sure this is what I need. Any database service would require querying and data transfer which is not what I'm looking for. My application is both data-intensive and computationally intensive so I need everything in memory instead of using ad-hoc queries which will for sure hurt performance by a lot.

Comment: If you're totally against using a database of any kind then I think using a self hosted service is you're best bet, I suggest NancyFx because it's easy to setup and self host, you could also use a TcpListener / TcpClient to create client server functions.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the self-hosted service so please bear with me. Doesn't it still follow the client/server model and by that would perform a data copy anyway when client requests it? I was looking for something along the line of directly accessing the data in memory just like it was created on the same process. Is it possible? So far from my research it seems that memory mapped file is the closest route.

Comment: even with a memory mapped file you're still going to be creating a .net object to work with so the memory is going to be used, web service will send a copy of the data but you need it anyway so does it matter?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you are going to keep 10GB of data in memory efficiently. Whatever approach you take 10GB of data in memory, is going to use system cache too often and is going to slow down your entire system.

I would suggest using a database if you can. If you cannot use database try to store your initialized data and read parts as and when needed with some caching.

Comment: On a windows server 64 bit OS with server-caliber RAM (32Gb or more) this shouldn't be an issue should it? A robust machine should not copy memory to disk if there is memory to spare, and will only use system cache once it runs out was my impression.

Comment: I was thinking the same here. didn't think that there was a caching issue. If you don't agree, can you elaborate on the problem?

Comment: I am not an expert on Windows memory management, but have always seen too much of swap to disk with windows, even with a lot of free ram left. But if you really need that much data in memory, then it is best to keep it in the applications space as you are doing it now. One thing you can do is don't ever shut down the application. Just hide it when the user closes the app. So only one time load that anyhow you need with any solution.